# IConverter C#,wpf ,checkbox.Checked

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2010

XAML Code

```
<TreeView.Resources>
  <local:BoolToVisibleOrHidden x:Key="BoolToVisConverter" Collapse="True"/>
</TreeView.Resources>
<TreeViewItem Header="First Child" Name="_firstChild"  
  Visibility="{Binding Path=VisibleOnCheck, Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisConverter}}" />
 <CheckBox Name="_checkBoxvisible" IsChecked="{Binding Path= VisibleOnCheck, Mode=TwoWay}" Content="show" Checked="CheckBox />
```

CheckBox Checked

```
private void CheckBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  if (MessageBox.Show("", "", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == 
    System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes)
  {   
    VisibleOnCheck = true;
  } 
  else
  {
    VisibleOnCheck = false; 
  }
}
```

MODEL CODE

```
Private bool __visible;
public bool VisibleOnCheck
{
    get { return _ visible; }
    set { _visible = value; OnPropertyChanged("VisibleOnCheck "); }
}

public class BoolToVisibleOrHidden : IValueConverter
{
    #region Constructors

    public BoolToVisibleOrHidden() { }
    #endregion

    #region Propertie Collapse

    public bool Collapse { get; set; }
    public bool Reverse { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region IValueConverter Members

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        bool bValue = (bool)value;

            if (bValue != Reverse)
            {
                return Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else
            {
                if (Collapse)
                    return Visibility.Collapsed;
                else
                    return Visibility.Hidden;
            }
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter,
                              System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
    {
        Visibility visibility = (Visibility) value;

        if (visibility == Visibility.Visible)
            return !Reverse;
        else
            return Reverse;
    }

    #endregion
    }
```

I want ,Treeview item header should visible when MessageBox .Yes clicked, but here its visible’s MessageBox and TreeviewItem same time without clicking Messagebox.yes, can any one help please.

Comment: Why are you using the WindowsForms `MessageBox`?

Comment: Did you check in the ouput window that you didn't have binding errors when launching the application?

Comment: sorry, actually am using my MessageBox(userControl).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a TwoWay binding on the CheckBox to `VisibleOnCheck`, so if you check the `Checkbox` its going to toggle the `Visibility` on the `TreeViewItem`.

If you want to handle the `VisibleOnCheck` in the Checked event handler based on the `DialogResult` you will have to remove the TwoWay binding or the binding altogether.

```
<CheckBox Name="_checkBoxvisible" Content="show" Checked="CheckBox />
```

I would also suggest using the `WPF` `MessageBox` over the `Winforms` one, seems a bit odd to drag in another framework for a `MessageBox`.

```
private void CheckBox(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   VisibleOnCheck = MessageBox.Show("","", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes;
}
```

---

### Edit

Since the problem is due to both controls binding to `VisibleOnCheck` you could just bind the `TreeViewItem` `Visibility` directly to the `Checkbox` in the `Xaml`

```
<TextBlock Text="TreeViewItem" Visibility="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkbx, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
<CheckBox x:Name="chkbx" Content="CheckBox" Checked="Checked"   />
```

and in the event just set the `IsChecked` based on your Dialog result

```
private void Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
     (sender as CheckBox).IsChecked = MessageBox.Show("","", MessageBoxButton.YesNo) == MessageBoxResult.Yes;
}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer but when i uncheck CheckBox, TreeviewItem still Visible , uncheck should inVisible. thanks

Comment: I don't think there is a way to only bind when the result is false only, why not just add an `Unchecked` event also, because the TwoWay `IsChecked` binding is going to happen before the `Checked` event is called, so you have to either pick binding or events, you wont get both working in the way you want, I have added another solution above that may work for you